# Trying to understand python memory profiler

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I am using [Memory Profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler#ipython-integration) module to get the memory usage of my python code following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105973/937153) answer. However, I am not able to interpret the output from `%memit` magic (or the output using the `@profile` decorator from the module or `mprof run` for that matter).

For instance,

```
%memit range(10000)
```

gives me `peak memory: 97.41 MiB, increment: 0.24 MiB`

while,

```
%memit xrange(10000)
```

shows `peak memory: 97.46 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB`. I do understand the difference between `xrange` returning an `xrange type` as opposed to `range()` returning a list. I used them here just to demonstrate the two scenarios.

My question is

1. What does `peak memory` and `increment` actually mean?
2. What should I report as the total memory usage of a script (or a function) from this output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Peak memory refers to the peak memory usage of your system (including memory usage of other processes) during the program runtime.

Increment is the increment in memory usage relative to the memory usage just before the program is run (i.e. `increment` = `peak memory` - `starting memory`).

So you'd report `increment`. Peak memory just helps you figure how close you are to using all your RAM during a program run.

If you refer to the line-by-line example in the usage section of the readme:

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
     3                           @profile
     4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
     5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
     8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

`%memit` is essentially giving you the memory usage from line 6, but reports the increment relative to line 4 (actually line 1, but presumably, there's no computation in lines 1-3).