# Strange increment value reported during IPython memory profiling

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, memory-profiling

While checking Jake van der Plas' "Python Data Science Handbook", I was recreating the usage examples of various debugging and profiling tools. He provides an example for demonstrating `%mprun` with the following function:

```
def sum_of_lists(N):
    total = 0
    for i in range(5):
        L = [j ^ (j >> i) for j in range(N)]
        total += sum(L)
        del L
    return total
```

I proceeded to execute it in a Jupyter notebook, and got the following output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     1     81.3 MiB     81.3 MiB   def sum_of_lists(N):
     2     81.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       total = 0
     3     81.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       for i in range(5):
     4    113.2 MiB -51106533.7 MiB           L = [j ^ (j >> i) for j in range(N)]
     5    119.1 MiB     23.5 MiB           total += sum(L)
     6     81.3 MiB   -158.8 MiB           del L
     7     81.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return total
```

... which immediately struck me as odd. According to the book, I should have gotten a 25.4 MiB increase on line 4, and a corresponding negative increase on line 6. But I have a massive negative increment instead, which does not line up at all to what I would have expected to happen. According to line 6, there should be a 158.8 increment.

On the other hand, `Mem usage` paints a more sensible picture (113.2 - 81.3 = 31.9 MiB increase). So I'm left with a weird, giant negative increment, and two measured changes in memory usage that don't agree with each other. What is going on, then?

Just to check if there's something truly bizarre going on with my interpreter/profiler, I went ahead and replicated the example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45318638/5106539), and got this output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     2     86.5 MiB     86.5 MiB   def my_func():
     3     94.1 MiB      7.6 MiB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     4    246.7 MiB    152.6 MiB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     5     94.1 MiB   -152.6 MiB       del b
     6     94.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a
```

Nothing wrong there, I think. What could be going on with the previous example?

Comment: I have some students struggling with a similar example, running `memory_profiler` on some code of their own. Unfortunately, I do not have an explanation (yet).

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out, but it looks like when a line runs more than once (either because it's in a loop or a comprehension), the increment that the profiler reports is summed over all executions of that line, while the usage reported (in the left column) is the memory usage during the last execution of the line. I'm just guessing, though.

Comment: Actually, I have a similar problem Has anyone found an answer?